# Twitter integration in blackberry using twitter_api_me-1.8.1 showing invalid characters on 9700

Tags: blackberry

I am using twitter_api_me-1.8.1 to integrate twitter in my blackberry application. Everything goes fine but the login page content is not displayed properly. (Displays squares and dots on the page. 9700). Any one faced this problem and has the solution, please help me.
Only black squares appearing.

Also on 9800 it is showing in english. After successfully login it's giving some pin number and asking to enter this pin number somewhere to complete your authorisation process. But not getting where to enter the same.

I have downloaded sample project from http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/downloads/directory/Miscellaneous

And jar files from here:
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2735#comment-form

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the login page content is not displayed properly. In BlackBerry

Then plz  follow this link.

Please, use BrowserFieldOAuthDialogWrapper in place of BrowserContentManagerOAuthDialogWrapper class. It works fine for me.

http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/forums/forum/topics/523812-A-test-for-invalid-characters-on-Blackberry#p571144

I got this success by the help of @ernandesmjr Ernandes Mourao Jr

If any find any issue. please let me know.

Thanks Ernandes